# w3 total cache and sitemap.xml

Tags: plugins, cache, sitemap

I have been installing lately w3 total cache on my wordpress site and today webmaster tools has been mailing an error by sitemap.xml crawling. `Sitemap ist HTML`. Is anybody experienced this issue with w3 total cache? If yes what would be the workaround?